# What does "noch stets" mean?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english, adverb, expression

What does "**noch stets**" mean? and is it the same as "immer noch"?

Example:

> Der Adler hat noch stets seine Zeit verschwendet, wenn er vom Raben
>   lernen wollte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a somewhat old-fashioned construction.

*noch* translates to *still* or *yet* and *stets* is a somewhat old-fashioned (but still in use) form of saying *always* or *ever*.

*noch immer* or *noch stets* is signalising that the speaker is anticipating dissent on their claim. The sentence could be translated as follows into English:

> Yet, the eagle has always wasted its time when wanting to learn from the raven.

This is not a perfect translation, since the starting *yet* seems a bit unmotivated, since there is nothing it refers to. In the German construction *noch stets* or *noch immer*, this is suggesting that the speaker anticipates dissent, and still believes their claim to be true.

Comment: +1, but it should be "wasted its time", otherwise well done.

Comment: @rexkogitans True, this was a slip of the pen. Thanks for mentioning, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the single words can be easily looked up in a dictionary: "yet" and "always".

This standing expression simply means "always", with a touch of "everyone should know".

Comment: "Noch" does not mean "ever". Its usual meaning is "still", but IMHO here it rather means "to date".